# Model not created at first runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my db module:

```
const config = require('../config.json');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectionOptions = { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false };
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || config.connectionString, connectionOptions);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports = {
    SessionCard: require('../models/sessioncard.model'),
    MotherCard: require('../models/mothercard.model'),
    Mother: require('../models/mother.model'),
    UserCard: require('../models/usercard.model'),
    Account: require('../models/account.model'),
    Price: require('../models/price.model'),
    Subscription: require('../models/subscription.model'),
    RefreshToken: require('../models/refresh-token.model'),
    isValidId
};

function isValidId(id) {
    return mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id);
}
```

And here is the price model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({

    price: {
        package1: { type: Number, default: 99, required: true }, 
        package3: { type: Number, default: 99, required: true }, 
        package6: { type: Number, default: 99, required: true },
        package12: { type: Number, default: 99, required: true }
    },

    discount: {
        package1: Number, 
        package3: Number, 
        package6: Number,
        package12: Number
    },

    expire: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Price', schema);
```

The issue is when I run the application for the very first time no price model being created at database?

How to have the model in database at first run time?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose only creates models that have index in them.

How I solved it was, I added to id -

```html
id: {
  default: new uuid(),
  type: String,
  unique: true
},
```